# corosync pacemaker nodes showing as online

Tags: synchronization, high-availability, pacemaker

I have setup two cluster nodes for HA using corosync, pacemaker and crmsh. Now all the services are up and I found a problem that two machines are not syncing properly, because of that both applications and VIP are running in parallel. How can I sync these applications?

```
OS version :Linux PCSCF 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 22:03:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

corosync.cfg

compatibility: whitetank

aisexec {
    # Run as root - this is necessary to be able to manage resources with Pacemaker
    user: root
    group: root
}
totem {
        version: 2
        secauth: off
        interface {
                member {
                        memberaddr: 10.193.30.16
                }
                member {
                        memberaddr: 10.193.30.22
                }
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: 10.193.30.31
                mcastport: 5405
        }
        transport: udpu
}
logging {
    fileline: on
    to_stderr: yes
    to_logfile: yes
    to_syslog: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    debug: on
    timestamp: on

logger_subsys {
    subsys: AMF
    debug: off
    }
}

service {

        name: corosync_quorum

        ver: 0

        name: pacemaker

        use_mgmtd: yes

        use_logd: yes

}...

quorum {

        provider: corosync_votequorum

        expected_votes: 3

        votes: 2

}

amf {
    mode: disabled
}

crm
node PCSCF
node PCSCF.techma.com \
    attributes standby=off
primitive VIP IPaddr2 \
    params ip=10.193.30.240 cidr_netmask=24 nic=eth0 \
    op monitor interval=10s \
    meta is-managed=true
primitive kamailio_ra ocf:myservice:kamailio_test \
    params listen_address=10.193.30.240 \
    op start interval=5s \
    op monitor interval=5s \
    meta migration-threshold=1 failure-timeout=5s target-role=Started
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
    stonith-enabled=false \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore \
    dc-version=1.1.11-97629de \
    cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
    last-lrm-refresh=1450073203 \
    start-failure-is-fatal=true \
    expected-quorum-votes=2
rsc_defaults rsc-options: \
    resource-stickiness=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks to be wrong

**corosync.conf(5) - Linux man page**

> bindnetaddr
>       This specifies the network address the corosync executive should bind to. For example, if the local interface is 192.168.5.92 with
>   netmask 255.255.255.0, set bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.0. If the local
>   interface is 192.168.5.92 with netmask 255.255.255.192, set
>   bindnetaddr to 192.168.5.64, and so forth.

So in your case probably
bindnetaddr: 10.193.30.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `corosync-cfgtool -s` command check standard output. corosync should not bind to 127.0.0.1 loopback address. If its bound to loopback address check /etc/hosts. hostname of node shouldn't be mapped to 127.0.0.1
2. To know that if there is split-brain run `pcs cluster status`
   It should be always `partition with quorum`
   [root@dmrfv1-mrfc-1 ~]# pcs cluster status
   Cluster Status:
   Stack: corosync
   Current DC: DMRFV1-MRFC-2 (version 1.1.16-12.el7_4.8-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
   Last updated: Wed Apr  3 06:47:35 2019
   Last change: Wed Apr  3 06:41:57 2019 by root via cibadmin on DMRFV1-MRFC-1
   2 nodes configured
   11 resources configured